# How does Visual studio know which library to link if both static and dynamic libraries exist?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, linker

When linking with external libraries, if both static and dynamic libraries exist in the same folder, which library will Visual Studio link?

As an example, for the boost filesystem library, the x64 static library file is **libboost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.lib** and the x64 dynamic library files are **boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.dll** and **boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.lib**. All these files are located in the same folder. When linking, how does Visual Studio linker know which one to use? Is it determined by the flag Runtime Library (/MT and /MD)?

Comment: It links to the libraries you tell it to link to, if you are using the boost auto linking then it'll link to whichever library boost tells it to link to

Comment: Should note that linking uses `.lib` files, not `.dll` ... The dll's come in during runtime.

Comment: @AlanBirtles For none boost libraries, how does Visual Studio know which one to use? One exmaple, I use a library called WebView2. The static lib file is called: WebView2LoaderStatic.lib and the dynamic lib files are: WebView2Loader.dll and WebView2Loader.dll.lib. They are all in the same folder. How does the linker know which lib to use when linking in this case?

Comment: It'll use whichever one you tell it to, the libraries have different names

Comment: The more precise terminology you didn't know you needed is that `boost_filesystem-vc142-mt-x64-1_77.lib` is an **import library** which is a special type of static library.  It is associated with a dynamic library, but is not a dynamic library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Yes, in case of `boost` choise is based on selected runtime in the project options (/MT or /ST).

Long version: =)

`Boost` library has an **autolinking** feature. This mechanism is defined in the header file `config/auto_link.hpp`. There boost is trying to determine full lib name basing on selected build architecture, toolset, threading options and so on. There are defines like `BOOST_DYN_LINK`, `BOOST_AUTO_LINK_NOMANGLE` which allow you to control this process. Also process could be controlled by library section specific defines for example: `BOOST_ASIO_DYN_LINK` for the `boost::asio`

Relevant section for selecting static/runtime library looks like this:

```
#if (defined(_DLL) || defined(_RTLDLL)) && defined(BOOST_DYN_LINK)
#  define BOOST_LIB_PREFIX
#elif defined(BOOST_DYN_LINK)
#  error "Mixing a dll boost library with a static runtime is a really bad idea..."
#else
#  define BOOST_LIB_PREFIX "lib"
#endif
```

Basicaly it depends on `_DLL` or `_RTLDLL` preprocessor option. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros?view=msvc-170)

> _DLL Defined as 1 when the /MD or /MDd (Multithreaded DLL) compiler option is set. Otherwise, undefined.

For other libraries you must specify **exact** library name to link against. This is done either in project options window (Linker/Input in case of MSVC), or by using directive `#pragma comment(lib libname)` directly in the source code. Failure to do that will lead to linker errors

Comment: For none boost libraries, how does Visual Studio know which one to use? As an exmaple, I use a library called WebView2. The static lib file is called: WebView2LoaderStatic.lib and the dynamic lib files are: WebView2Loader.dll and WebView2Loader.dll.lib. They are all in the same folder. How does the linker know which lib to link? Do all libraries have similar autolinking feature like boost?

Comment: No. Most libraries require you to specify exact library name to link against. It is done either in project options window (Linker/Input) or by using directive `#pragma comment (lib)`

Comment: @OptimusPrime: If you put `WebView2LoaderStatic.lib` in the project "Linker Inputs" option, you get static linking, if you put `WebView2Loader.lib` in, you get DLL imports.